# Save a dynamic HTML table in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my code below user choose a color and types customer name and adds the data to a dynamic table. **My problem is that I want to save my table in JSON but my code saves only the first row of the table and it doesn't adds rest of the rows**

```js
function colorddRow() {
  var colorpartsrows = "";
  var colparts = $("#color-part-list").val();
  var customer = $("#customer-name").val();

  var colpartssum = $("#color-part-list :selected").length;

  colorpartsrows +=
    "<tr><td>" +
    colparts +
    "</td><td>" +
    customer +
    "</td><td>" +
    colpartssum +
    "</td></tr>";
  $(colorpartsrows).appendTo("#dataTable1-color-parts tbody");
}

function showValues() {
  var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
  $("#results").empty();
  jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    $("#results").append(field.value + " ");
  });
}
$("select").change(showValues);
showValues();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th name="color[]" id="color">Color</th>
    <th name="Customer[]" id="customer">Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="color-des">
      <select id="color-part-list" data-placeholder="Rejected Parts">
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="customer">
      <input id="customer-name" type="text" name="customer">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add The Color" onclick="colorddRow()" />

<table id="dataTable1-color-parts">
 <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
</tr>  
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="showValues()">Save to JSON</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that...

```js
const   // ------------------------------------------------------- ↓↓↓↓↓ added!
    result_Table = document.querySelector('#dataTable1-color-parts tbody')
  , select_Color = document.querySelector('#color-part-list')
  , custom_Color = document.querySelector('#customer-name')
  ;
function colorddRow()
  {
  let newRow = result_Table.insertRow()
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = select_Color.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = custom_Color.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = "1"
  }
function showValues()
  {
  let jsonTable = []
  for (let r=0; r<result_Table.rows.length; ++r)
    {
    let colparts = result_Table.rows[r].cells[0].textContent
      , customer = result_Table.rows[r].cells[1].textContent
      , sum      = result_Table.rows[r].cells[2].textContent
      ;
    jsonTable.push( {colparts,customer,sum} )
    }
  console.clear()
  console.log( jsonTable )
  }
```

```css
#dataTable1-color-parts  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
#dataTable1-color-parts th,
#dataTable1-color-parts td {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
#dataTable1-color-parts thead {
  background-color:  #c3e3ee;
  }
  
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:50% !important; width:50%; }
.as-console-row         { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
.as-console-row::before { content: 'JSON'; font-size: .8em; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th name="color[]" id="color">Color</th>
    <th name="Customer[]" id="customer">Color</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="color-des">
      <select id="color-part-list">
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
        <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="customer">
      <input id="customer-name" type="text" name="customer">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add The Color" onclick="colorddRow()" />

<table id="dataTable1-color-parts">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>colparts</th><th>customer</th><th>sum</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="showValues()">Save to JSON</button>
```

Comment: If in the first row of my table I have a table headline, is there any way to exclude it from going to the JSON?

Comment: yes, it works the same ( with tbody and thead). I have updated my code for showing that.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to save input, your want to save cell text

```js
const arr = []

function colorddRow() {
  var colparts = $("#color-part-list").val();
  var customer = $("#customer-name").val();

  var colpartssum = $("#color-part-list :selected").length;
  if (colparts && customer && colpartssum) {
    arr.push({ colparts, customer, colpartssum });
    $("#dataTable1-color-parts tbody").html(
      arr.map(({ colparts, customer, colpartssum }) => `<tr><td>${colparts}</td><td>${customer}</td><td>${colpartssum}</td></tr>`).join(""))
  }
}

function showValues() {
  $("#results").html(
    arr.length > 0 ? JSON.stringify(arr) : ""
  )
}

$("#add").on("click", colorddRow)
$("#save").on("click", showValues)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th name="color[]" id="color">Color</th>
      <th name="Customer[]" id="customer">Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="color-des">
        <select id="color-part-list" data-placeholder="Rejected Parts">
          <option value="Red">Red</option>
          <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
          <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="White">White</option>
          <option value="Black">Black</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="customer">
        <input id="customer-name" type="text" name="customer">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Add The Color" id="add" />

<button type="button" id="save">Save to JSON</button>
<p><b>Results:</b> <span id="results"></span></p>
<table id="dataTable1-color-parts">
  <tr>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is your code saving all the dynamic rows to the JSON?

Comment: Now it is. I had to re-read the code and your question. You do not want to save :input. See my update

Comment: @CoderJay I missed your table update. I also now only create JSON if there is something in the cell

Comment: what about `colpartssum` value (allways ==1) ? the length of nothing ?

Comment: `$("#color-part-list :selected").length;` is always 1

Comment: I simplified the whole thing. Only necessary to add to the array and render it each time